# How to write a matlab code for a given algorithm from a given array and function?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I would like to write a matlab code to calculate the value of a function of two variables g(i,j) = i + j + 1  for every pair (i,j) in the set  MV = {(1,3), (2,4), (5,6), (5,4), (7,2)}  so that the output results in g = {5, 7, 12, 10, 9} based on the following algorithm:

```
Step 0.  MV_0 = empty set;
Step 1.   h=1;
Step 2.  while MV_h ~= empty set {
Step 3.     for every (i,j) in MV {
Step 4.            g(i,j)
Step 5.     }
Step 6.    h=h++
Step 7.      }
```

So far I have tried the following, but I couldn't figure it out.  Please any hint/assistance. Thanks in advance!

```
MV = {}; % Step 0
h = 1; % Step 1
%  MV= intersect(r(r==1),s(s==3)) 
while isempty(MV{h})==0 % MV{h} is nonempty from Step 2
    MV = {[1,3], [2,4], [5,6], [5,4], [7,2]}
    
    % Step 3,  for every (i,j) in EMV{h}
    for i=1:length(MV)
        for j = 1:length(MV)     
              MV{h} = g(i,j); % Step 4    
        end
    end
    h = h+1;   % Step 6
end

g % to get the final result g = {5, 7, 12, 10, 9}

% subfunction
function y = g(i,j)
y = i+j+1;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess u need the following:

```
function Camp()
clear,clc
MV = {}; 
h = 1; 
while isempty(MV)
    
    MV = {[1,3], [2,4], [5,6], [5,4], [6,2]};
    
    for m = 1:length(MV) 
        i = MV{m}(1);
        j = MV{m}(2);
       MV{h} = g(i,j)
       h = h+1;   
    end
    
end
end

% sub function
function y = g(i,j)
y = i+j+1;
end
```

Output is:

```
MV = 

  Columns 1 through 3

    [5]    [7]    [12]

  Columns 4 through 5

    [10]    [9]
```